# Remove space between QWidgets

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

With the following code I generate a window with buttons:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets>

class Item : public QWidget {
    QHBoxLayout hLayout{this};
    QPushButton bt{"button"};
public:
    Item() : QWidget() {
        hLayout.addWidget(&bt);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    QVBoxLayout vLayout(&w);
    vLayout.addWidget(new Item());
    vLayout.addWidget(new Item());
    vLayout.addWidget(new Item());
    vLayout.addWidget(new Item());
    vLayout.addWidget(new Item());
    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

[image]

With `layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)` I can go to:

[image]

Is it possible to reduce even more space between buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `setSpacing` method :

```
vLayout.setSpacing(0);
```

But I think the real issue here would be that your layout is stretched out to cover whole widget and it arranges layout items accordingly.

Another thing you can try is to set the margin :

```
vLayout.setMargin(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the space, by adjusting the spacing:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#spacing-prop

Setting it to `0` should bring the widgets together.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    QVBoxLayout vLayout(&w);
    vLayout.addWidget(new Item());
    ...

    // Removes outer margins
    vLayout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0);

    // Set space between items to '0'
    vLayout.setSpacing(0);

    w.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

In your example above you should probably also add a strech section:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qboxlayout.html#addStretch